# Return value from another column based on index of searched value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas Dataframe that looks like this.

```
0| 1 | 2 | 3
0|8/2/22| Jim's number -223-| Evan's number -4566-
1|8/3/22| Al's number -354L-| Tess's number -45366-
2|8/4/22| Eric's number -35034-| Daniel's number -LP4566-
3|8/5/22| John's number -35478-| Jacob's number -XF4T67-
```

I am trying to write a script that will allow me to search through columns 2 and 3 based off of that number, -224- (as an example), and then get the index so I can search column 1. Essentially, I am trying to match the value in columns 2 or 3 to column 1. Finding that number and pairing it to a date.

What is the best way to do this as I have been stuck trying to get the index off of only a partial string value (-224).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({1:['8/2/22','8/3/22'], 2:['Jim\'s number -223-', 'Al\'s number -354L-']})
df.loc[df[2].str.contains('-223-'), 1]
```

```
    1       2
0   8/2/22  Jim's number -223-
1   8/3/22  Al's number -354L-
```

```
0    8/2/22
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Comment: I get a keyerror 2 when I run that code

Comment: it runs fine for me. Are you using your own dataframe? Make sure the name is integer 2 not str `'2'`

Comment: Thanks for you help, I changed the dataframe a little bit since I forgot to mention I am looking for these values in multiple columns and not just in column 2.

Comment: you can use `df[2].str.contains('-223-') | df[3].str.contains('-223-')`